# What should I do when I think my comment should be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

I've left a comment on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1506059) explaining why I have downvoted it and how it could be improved. Other user replied, I replied and the comments section eventually got too chatty, so all comments were removed (which was a right action IMO).

I thought that the first comment could still be useful for answer's author, so I've flagged the answer for moderator's attention, adding a message:

> I left a comment on this answer explaining how it could be improved. It seems that it was deleted.

The flag was declined with a message:

> No idea why you are flagging because a comment was deleted.

I'm quite confused. I didn't state explicitly that I think the comment should be undeleted, but I thought it's clear from the context. **What should I do to let moderators know that I think a comment should be undeleted?**

Answer (score 5):

#### What should I do to let moderators know that I think a comment should be undeleted?

Hand up, I handled that flag.

You did the right thing by flagging, however there were not enough characters available to explain why I didn't undelete your comment.

You said in the flag text:

> I left a comment on this answer explaining how it could be improved. It seems that it was deleted.

And here is the comment:

> -1 from me. You state that experiment is necessary, while the other answer already explains that it's possible to verify this without experimentation. There's also a comment on the question that explains that one experiment wouldn't prove anything in general because there's a variety of i7s, Xeons and motherboards. What works on one motherboard model may not be the case for another one.

That comment, in my opinion, does not explain what the poster needs to do to improve their answer.

You then started an exchange of comments with another user, who then flagged one of your comments (a different one).

Another mod handled that flag and decided the correct course of action was to delete all of the comments.

Comment: Fair enough, on a second thought that really doesn't help make the answer better. Still, I think without this explanation answer's author can consider my downvote undeserved.